# Estimating Number of Scratch Tickets Remaining

Tags: probability, statistics, education

So, in my statistics class we discussed the recent huge jackpot, but we decided to focus on something more "trackable"—scratch tickets.
A part of the assignment is to figure out how many tickets are remaining given the following data: `chances of winning`, `number of prize brackets`, `number of prizes in each bracket`, and `number of prizes remaining in each bracket`.

I've made the following example in order to figure out an approach to solve this: `1 in 3 chance of winning`, `3 prize brackets (e.g. $50, $25, $5)`, `1, 3, 7, prizes in each bracket (respectively)` and `1, 2, 5, prizes remaining (respectively)`.

Obviously, we know for a fact that at least 3 tickets were sold `(3-2)+(7-5) = 3`, meaning that there are 30 tickets left. However, this isn't the best conclusion for how many tickets are remaining given that the chances of winning are 1 in 3.

I'm having trouble figuring out how the 1 in 3, would factor in to show how possibly more than 3 tickets were sold given the number of prizes already claimed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of prizes between buckets does not matter when estimating the number of tickets sold so far, so the useful information is, as you say:

- Initial probability of winning $\frac13$
- Initial number of prizes: $11$
- Remaining number of prizes: $8$
- so number of prizes won so far: $11-8=3$
- and initial number of tickets: $3 \times 11 = 33$

One approach might be to say that $3$ prizes have been won so far and a third of tickets overall win prizes, so a reasonable estimate here is that $3 / \frac13 =9$ have been sold and that $33-9=24$ remain.  This approach will give an unbiased estimator.

Another approach, which happens to give the same answer in this particular question, is to consider the likelihood of seeing this after $n$ tickets have been sold, which is (based on the hypergeometric distribution) is $$\dfrac{\displaystyle {11 \choose 3}{22 \choose n-3}}{\displaystyle{33 \choose n}}$$  and this is positive for $3 \le n \le 25$ and is maximised when $n=9$. So $9$ is the maximum likelihood estimate of the number of tickets which have been sold given that $3$ out of $33$ prizes have already been won, corresponding to $24$ tickets remaining.